# Measure FPS of Application in console mode

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux

I am comparing two applications and therefore need to know which fps a raspberry can produce when you run it. I am looking for a method to do this. It does not matter if it is an overlay or a simple console output that I could log.

The RPI runs in console mode and is connected to a touchscreen.
If possible, the method should not be based on a specific graphics API, since the applications I test may vary depending on the graphics API used.

If I have forgotten a necessary detail, please tell me.
Thanks :)

Comment: I think hardware FPS is 60 Hz for most modes. Software FPS will necessarily depend on specific application and graphics API.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yeah, that's what I'm searching for... a method to measure the Software FPS

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get an answer for this as the software FPS depends on the software and libraries used.

Even the 'hardware' FPS rate is set in software (see RPF site [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md)) and the standard modes support

- 240Hz
- 200Hz
- 120Hz
- 100Hz
- 60Hz
- 50Hz
- 30Hz
- 25Hz
- 24Hz
- And lots more that I will not list!